# Nonlinear (non-polynomial) cost function with DirectCollocation in Drake

Tags: drake

I am trying to formulate a trajectory optimization problem for a glider, where I want to maximize the average horisontal velocity. I have formulated the system as a drakesystem, and the state vector consists of the position and velocity.

Currently, I have something like the following:

```
dircol = DirectCollocation(
    plant,
    context,
    num_time_samples=N,
    minimum_timestep=min_dt,
    maximum_timestep=max_dt,
)

... # other constraints etc

horisontal_pos = dircol.state()[0:2] # Only (x,y)
time = dircol.time()
dircol.AddFinalCost(-w.T.dot(horisontal_pos) / time)
```

where AddFinalCost() should replace all instances of state() and time() with the final values, as far as I understand from the documentation. `min_dt` is non-zero and `w` is a vector of linear weights.

However, I am getting the following error message

`Expression (...) is not a polynomial. ParseCost does not support non-polynomial expression.`

which makes me think that there is no way of adding the type of cost function that I am looking for. Is there anything that I am missing?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `AddFinalCost(e)` with `e` being a symbolic expression, we can only handle it when `e` is a polynomial function of the state (more precisely, either a quadratic function or a linear function). Hence the error you see complaining that the cost is not polynomial.

You could add the cost like this

```py
def average_speed(v):
    x = v[0]
    time_steps = v[1:]
    return v[0] / np.sum(time_steps)
    
h_vars = [dircol.timestep[i] for i in range(N-1)]
dircol.AddCost(average_speed, vars=[dircol.state(N-1)[0]] + h_vars)
```

which uses a function `average_speed` to evaluate the average speed. You could find example of doing this in https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/e5f3c3e5f7927ef675066d97d3afac55d3481305/bindings/pydrake/solvers/test/mathematicalprogram_test.py#L590

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Follow-up: is it still the case that Drake can't handle non-polynomial cost functions? In particular, I'm hoping to put a `min` or `exp` function as part of the cost

Comment: @njk23, you can add non-polynomial cost, but just not a symbolic form. See the example above where we add a cost using a function `average_speed`.

Answer (score 0):

First, the cost function should be a scalar, but you a vector-valued `horisontal_pos / time`, which has two entries containing both `position_x / dt` and `position_y / dt`, namely a vector as the cost. You should instead provide a scalar valued cost.

Second, it is unclear to me why you divide `time` in the final cost. As far as I understand it, you want the final position to be close to the origin, so something like `position_x² + position_y²`. The code can look like

```
dircol.AddFinalCost(horisontal_pos[0]**2 + horisontal_pos[1]**2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I am sorry, I had a typo in the pseudocode, the cost function is in fact scalar (it is the vector product between a weight vector and hor_pos), I have updated it now.

The goal of the optimization is to find the trajectory that maximizes the average velocity over the flight path. Maybe I am misunderstanding you, but can't quite see how your cost function gives will maximize the average velocity?